# Adding massive in new form from existing form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Form1` in C# and added to project a new form - `Form2` (Add/New Item...).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

How can I use `massive mass_1` in `Form2`, that created in`Form1`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using MVC, you can pass in `mass_1` in the `Form2()` constructor, or set it as a property of `Form2`.

Better would be to use a Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture.  One example for how to implement MVC with WinForms:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp